# App crashes when getting Back using Intent

Tags: android

My application crashed when I'm trying to navigate from one activity to another.I have a menu page which consists of buttons,when i hit the first button it takes me to another activity, but when i am trying to get back to my menu activity i am getting null pointer exceptions.I don't know what is the problem exactly?

```
    Intent  intent = new Intent(VehicleNo.this,OptionMenuAct.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

I am using the above code to get back to menu page.I am getting problem in oncreate function.this is the code for that

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option_menu);



    t_row1=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row1);
    t_row2=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row2);
    t_row3=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row3);
    t_row4=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row4);
    t_row5=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row5);
    t_row6=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row6);
    t_row7=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row7);
    t_row8=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row101);
    t_row9=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.t_row102);


    ArrayList<String> pv = new ArrayList<String>();

    pv = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("values");

    for (String s : pv) 
    {
        Log.d("k", s);
    }
```

Comment: you are not passing `values` when starting new activity and trying to get from intent so the exception

Comment: use finish() only in onBackPressed(); or pass putExtra("values" , yourarraylist); with intent

Comment: You might be getting @Nullpointer while extracting value from intent. Pass value of ArrayList in the intent to get it working and also add a null check while extracting value to avoid crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to back to menu page,you can call `this.finish()` to destory current activity and back to menu page activity.

Answer (score 1):

Your OnCreate method uses its intent and it should have an stringarraylist along with it, you are passing no such a thing.
try to pass your desired stringarraylist when you are starting your menu activity

Comment: I just want to go to that activity.I have nothing to pass that array list is coming from another activity.I got what you are trying to say but is there any other solution for this

Comment: i think if you just use finish() in your VehicleNo.class you are good to go, but do not finish your OptionMenuAct.class when user clicks on options